# What is causing an issue with amazon-cognito-identity-js@6.2.0 in my React Native app after updating packages?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito-identity-js

[image]Updated React native app and packages but facing problem in amazon-cognito-identity-js

Kindly help me to resolve my issue

Versions
"amazon-cognito-identity-js": "6.2.0"
"aws-amplify": "^5.2.4",
"react-native": "^0.71.8",

Thankyou

Provide me solution of this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.